# Error when inserting to the collection in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-collection2, simple-schema

I'm using meteor with SimpleSchema and Collection2. And react. I faced with error when inserting an item to the collection. here is the code:

my collection and schema in **recipes.js:**

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';
import { SimpleSchema } from 'meteor/aldeed:simple-schema';

export const Recipes = new Mongo.Collection('recipes');

Recipes.deny({
  insert() { return true; },
  update() { return true; },
  remove() { return true; },
});

RecipeSchema = new SimpleSchema({
  name: {
    type: String,
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
  },
  author: {
    type: String,
    autoValue: function() {
      return Meteor.userId();
    },
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    autoValue: function() {
      if(Meteor.isClient){
            return this.userId;
      } else if(Meteor.isServer){
            return Meteor.userId();
        }
    },
  }
});

Recipes.attachSchema(RecipeSchema);
```

My methods code in **Methods.js**

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';
import { SimpleSchema } from 'meteor/aldeed:simple-schema';

import { Recipes } from './recipes.js';

 Meteor.methods({
   'recipes.insert'(name, desc) {
     new SimpleSchema({
       name: { type: String },
       desc: { type: String },
     }).validate({ name, desc });

     Recipes.insert({
       name,
       description: desc,
     });
   }
});
```

And in file AddRecipeForm.jsx in the **handleSubmit** method of the component I get the values of the inputs (name and desc) and then call `Meteor.call('recipes.insert', name, desc);`. I want field Author and CreatedBy to create automatically on the server with simple-schema autoValue.

But I have an error always when I am trying to inset something with the form:

> insert failed: Error: Author is required

I tried to add this code to the **recipe.insert** method:

```
let newRecipe = {
  name,
  description: desc,
}

RecipeSchema.clean(newRecipe);
Recipes.insert(newRecipe);
```

But that didn't work. And in official simple-schema docs I've found that is not necessary:

> NOTE: The Collection2 package always calls clean before every insert, update, or upsert.

I solved this problem as adding `optional: true` to the fields `Author` and `CreatedAt` in my **RecipeSchema**. so code for the author field is:

```
author: {
    type: String,
    optional: true,
    autoValue: function() {
      return this.userId;
    },
  },
```

But I don't want this fields to be optional. I just want to `autoValue` works and this fields will be filled with the right values. Who knows why this error occurs and how to solve it?

**Update**

I noticed one important moment. I inserted different recipies with my form (that i think is working wrong because of the `optional: true`). when I run `meteor mongo` > `db.recipes.findOne()' and get different recipies, I get objects like these:

```
meteor:PRIMARY> db.recipes.findOne()

{
        "_id" : "RPhPALKtC7dXdzbeF",
        "name" : "Hi",
        "description" : "hiodw",
        "author" : null,
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-05-12T17:57:15.585Z")
}
```

So i don't know why, but fields Author and CreatedBy are filled correct (author: null beacuse i have no accounts system yet). but in this way, what is the meaning of **required** and **optinal** in schema? is my solution (with `optional: true`) correct?

**update 2**

another important moment! i removed `author` field from the schema. and removed `optional:true` from the `createdBy` field. and it works! tithout optional true. I realized that actual problem is in **author field* of the schema. but WHAT is the problem?

Comment: By default, all keys are required. Set optional: true to change that.

Comment: I already wrote that i solved the problem this way. but i don't understand the meaning of it.

Comment: weird situation that it even works without optional:true! need to remove author field - and it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is internal Framework issue, I guess. Your First code looks perfectly alright. Instead of posting this question here, you can post it on aldeed: collection2 github repository. The concerned people who maintain it will look into the issue.